# How to call the function of the adapter of child fragment method from its activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

**What Structure I am having:**

1. I Have a Activity called `MainActivity.java`
2. Inside `MainActivity.java` there is `ParentFragment.java`
3. Now inside `ParentFragment.java` there is `ChildFragment.Java`
4. Now inside `ChildFragment.Java` there is a adapter for it
   `ChildAdapter.java`
5. Inside `ChildAdapter.java` the is a method called `MyMethod()`

**Now How to access the `MyMethod()` in `MainActivity.java`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

1.Find `ParentFragment` in `MainActivity` by its TAG

2.And from the `ParentFragemnt` instance find `ChildFragment` with its TAG using `getChildSupportManager()`

3.And now create `ChildAdapter` variable global in `ChildFragment` and make it public

4.And from `ChildFragment` instance access the `ChildAdapter`

5.And than you can access `MyMethod()` from `ChildAdapter` variable

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this method in the Activity which has to replace the Fragments:

```
 /**
 * This method is used to load the fragment once an item gets selected
 *
 * @param fragment This is the chosen fragment you want to select
 */
public void loadFragmentActivityFrameLayout(final Fragment fragment) {

    // create a transaction for transition here
    final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();

    // put the fragment in place
    transaction.replace(
            R.id.frameLayoutId,
            fragment,
            fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

    // this is the part that will cause a fragment to be added to back stack,
    // this way we can return to it at any time using this tag
        if(fragment instanceof Fragment1){
            transaction.addToBackStack(Fragmen1.class.getSimpleName());
        }else if(fragment instanceof Fragment2){
            transaction.addToBackStack(Fragment2.class.getSimpleName());
        }else if(fragment instance of Fragment3){
            transaction.addToBackStack(Fragment3.class.getSimpleName());
        }else if(fragment instanceof Fragment4){
            transaction.addToBackStack(Fragment4.class.getSimpleName());
        }

    transaction.commit();
}
```

And then you can retrieve an instance of each Fragment in that Activity, like this:

```
Fragment1 frag1 =
            (Fragment1)getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(Fragment1.class.getSimpleName());

Fragment2 frag2  =
            (Fragment2)getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(Fragment2.class.getSimpleName());

Fragment3 frag3 =
            (Fragment3)getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(Fragment3.class.getSimpleName());

Fragment4 frag4 =
            (Fragment4)getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(Fragment4.class.getSimpleName());
```

And then, since you got an adapter, make it public in its Fragment, let's say "frag1", **don't forget to make "MyMethod()" also public into the adapter** :

```
public CustomAdapter adapter;
```

And finally you can retrieve any adapter method from the Activity:

```
frag1.adapter.MyMethod();
```

Hope I've been clear.